# Differences when accessing a file with Python?

Tags: python, string, file, text-files, difference

Learning about different access methods that can be used when opening a file with Python.
What is the difference between opening a file for both reading and writing vs. opening a file for both writing and reading?

when using the `open()` function you can use any any of these to open a file:

- r
- r+
- w
- w+
- a
- a+

my question is really would there be a different outcome when using either r+ vs w+ to open files?

Comment: Consider reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `r+` and `w+` is that `w+` will empty the file first. So you typically use `r+` if you want to read the file first, then write to it. You use `w+` if you want to write to the file first, then read what you've written.

`a+` automatically positions to the end of the file when it's first opened and before every write. So you can use it similarly to `r+`, but you have to seek first if you want to read what's already in the file, and all writes are appended to the end.

The modes without `+` just allow reading or writing, not both.